# Git клиент и ошибка 403

Tags: git

У меня не получается склонировать приватный репозиторий с github

> -bash-4.1$  git clone https://github.com/WISHPRO/glaz glazapp.info
> Initialized empty Git repository in /var/www/u0018194/data/www/glazapp.info/.git/
> error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/WISHPRO/glaz/info/refs
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed

git даже не запрашивает логин и пароль, а просто выдает ошибку 403. Подскажите, что делать? Может нужно что то где то прописать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ссылка точно правильная? Я бы попробовал через ssh на всякий склонировать (хотя по-хорошему клиент действительно должен просто запросить логин и пароль)

Comment: Всё разобрался, нужно было сгенерировать ключ, и использовать ssh